# Hoshen Kopelman algorithm for cluster detection

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I'm fairly new to the programming scene and quite overwhelmed :D I want to apply the `Hoshen-Kopelman` algorithm for cluster detection in a matrix and then determine the "size" of the largest cluster. For this, I have written the following code (see below). However, some clusters are labeled incorrectly, depending on the example matrix (for example, in my code, clusters 3 and 6 should be the same cluster). Could someone help me with debugging?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self, max_labels):
        self.labels = np.zeros(max_labels, dtype=np.uint8)
        self.labels[0] = 0
        self.n_labels = max_labels

    def find(self, x):
        y = x
        if self.labels[y] != y:
            y = self.labels[y]
        if self.labels[x] != x:
            z = self.labels[x]
            self.labels[x] = y
            x = z
        return y

    def union(self, x, y):
        self.labels[self.find(x)] = self.find(y)
        return self.find(x)

    def make_set(self):
        self.labels[0] += 1
        assert self.labels[0] < self.n_labels
        self.labels[self.labels[0]] = self.labels[0]
        return self.labels[0]


def hoshen_kopelman(matrix, m, n):
    uf = UnionFind(m * n // 2)
    cluster_sizes = {} 

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if matrix[i][j]:
                up = matrix[i - 1][j] if i > 0 else 0
                left = matrix[i][j - 1] if j > 0 else 0
    
                if up == 0 and left == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = uf.make_set()
                elif up == 0 or left == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = max(up, left)
                else:
                    matrix[i][j] = uf.union(up, left)

                label = matrix[i][j]
                cluster_sizes[label] = cluster_sizes.get(label, 0) + 1

    largest_cluster_size = max(cluster_sizes.values())
    matrix_size = m * n
    largest_cluster_ratio = largest_cluster_size / matrix_size

    return matrix, largest_cluster_ratio

matrix1 = np.array([
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

hkm, largest_cluster_ratio = hoshen_kopelman(matrix1, 6, 6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
min_val = 0
max_val = 6
m = 6
n = 6
ax.matshow(hkm, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        c = hkm[i, j]
        ax.text(j, i, str(c), va='center', ha='center')

plt.show()

print("size of the largest cluster(ratio to the matrix size):", largest_cluster_ratio)
```

cluster labeling in my example
[image]

Comment: Debugging is the best way to become a better programmer. Add print statements at junctures where something is computed to verify that your program is progressing as it should. If your output is not what you expect, trace back along your code to find where the first unexpected thing happens. Debugging can be hard and very different types of bugs exist, from mundane to pernicious. Debugging can take a lot of time, and that time is always well spent, even if just to remind you next time to invest time in testing whilst writing code.

Comment: @Adam98 this is a known limitation in the original algorithm due to the limited `up & left` neighborhood, and that's why an extended algorithm was proposed later, to solve this problem "*resolve the indirections*" by using a 4 connectivity pattern `up down left right`